# Debugging RtlUserThreadStart in Process Explorer

Tags: c#, multithreading, process-explorer

I have a multi-threaded wpf application built on 3.5. When I look at the running threads through Process Explorer I see 8 threads all with the same start address, ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart and all eight have a CPU value from 3-6+ and have a high Cycles Delta. I can't figure out what these threads are doing. It is always the same threads. It never varies within the same instance of the application. When I debug my application at the same time and pause the debugger, all these threads are showing a single line for the stack either System.Threading.ConcurrencyScheduler.Scheduler.WaitForWork() or System.Threading.Monitor.Wait().

I enabled the symbol files for Visual Studio and I see the following stack on those threads:

```
System.Threading.Monitor.Wait() Normal
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Monitor.Wait(object obj, int millisecondsTimeout) + 0x19     bytes
System.Threading.dll!System.Threading.ConcurrencyScheduler.Scheduler.WaitForWork() + 0xd0 bytes  
System.Threading.dll!System.Threading.ConcurrencyScheduler.InternalContext.Dispatch() + 0x74a bytes
System.Threading.dll!System.Threading.ConcurrencyScheduler.ThreadInternalContext.ThreadStartBridge(System.IntPtr dummy) + 0x9f bytes
```

When I look at the stack provided on the thread within process monitor I see the following as examples:

```
0  ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc0a
1  ntoskrnl.exe!KeAcquireSpinLockAtDpcLevel+0x732
2  ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForSingleObject+0x19f
3  ntoskrnl.exe!_misaligned_access+0xba4
4  ntoskrnl.exe!_misaligned_access+0x1821
5  ntoskrnl.exe!_misaligned_access+0x1a97
6  mscorwks.dll!InitializeFusion+0x990b
7  mscorwks.dll!DeleteShadowCache+0x31ef
```

or:

```
0  ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc0a
1  ntoskrnl.exe!KeAcquireSpinLockAtDpcLevel+0x732
2  ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForSingleObject+0x19f
3  ntoskrnl.exe!_misaligned_access+0xba4
4  ntoskrnl.exe!_misaligned_access+0x1821
5  ntoskrnl.exe!KeAcquireSpinLockAtDpcLevel+0x93d
6  ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0x26a
7  ntoskrnl.exe!NtWaitForSingleObject+0x41f
8  ntoskrnl.exe!NtWaitForSingleObject+0x78e
9  ntoskrnl.exe!KeSynchronizeExecution+0x3a23
10 ntdll.dll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xa
11 KERNELBASE.dll!GetCurrentProcess+0x40
12 KERNEL32.dll!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xb3
13 mscorwks.dll!CreateApplicationContext+0x10499
14 mscorwks.dll!CreateApplicationContext+0xbc41
15 mscorwks.dll!StrongNameFreeBuffer+0xc54d
16 mscorwks.dll!StrongNameFreeBuffer+0x2ac48
17 mscorwks.dll!StrongNameTokenFromPublicKey+0x1a5ea
18 mscorwks.dll!CopyPDBs+0x17362
19 mscorwks.dll!CorExitProcess+0x3dc9
20 mscorwks.dll!TranslateSecurityAttributes+0x547f
21 mscorlib.ni.dll+0x8e6bc9
```

As an additional note to this item. My computer is a single CPU with 4 cores. When we run the same app on a dual CPU with 4 cores we see this number of threads go from 8 to 16.

Comment: You are going to need to get better debugging symbols if this is how you want to debug it.  Any symbol that appears with an offset more than 0x100 is basically junk and doesn't tell you what is really going on.  Right now you can only see exported functions.  Enable the Microsoft symbol server to get better pdbs.

Comment: I added the stack the Visual Studio provides when enabling the symbol server. I don't know how to augment the stack provided from within Process Explorer

Comment: BTW: Process Explorer seems to show "RtlUserThreadStart" if it has not full permission to see the image. For example I noticed this when a MSI installer is running. When you use the "File -> Show All Process Information" setting, it will resolve the stack to deeper elements. (You also notice that the "Stack Trace" button prints an error without the elevated priveledges.

Answer (score 6):

Your question is woefully under-documented, but a reasonable guess is that you appear to use the PPL library.  Which keeps a pool of threads around to get the parallel jobs done.  You are no doubt seeing high cpu cycle counts because these threads are indeed doing the job you asked them to do.

As is typical with thread pools, the PPL keeps these threads around for the next job to do, that's why you see them waiting on WaitForWork().  The native stack traces are junk due to a lack of debugging symbols.  RtlUserThreadStart is otherwise a Windows function you'll always see back in an unmanaged stack trace, that's how a thread gets started.

This is all entirely normal.  The only other info worth of note is [this answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/parallelcppnative/thread/8542425d-db3e-4334-9cdd-3ff0f5911f24) posted by a Microsoft employee:

> The concurrency runtime caches threads for later re-use. They are released only when all the concurrency runtime schedulers have been shutdown. (Typically, there is just a single default scheduler in the process). A scheduler is shutdown when all the external threads that queued work to it has exited. So if the main thread scheduled work (by calling parallel_for from main() say) then the default scheduler would be deleted only on process shutdown.
>
> There is an upper limit on the number of cached threads. It is rougly 4 times the number of cores on the machine (though there are some other factors affecting the threshold like the stack size option in scheduler policies).

Comment: I understand the concept of maintaining these threads for later use. What I don't understand or know how to debug is why are they each consuming so much cpu when they are just waiting around for work? I see each one consuming 3-6+% of cpu

Comment: Because these threads are actually doing work?  You wrote a "multi-threaded wpf application", they are supposed to do work.  Process Explorer isn't going to be helpful to catch them sometimes doing work.  When it makes the snapshot, it is using one core of your CPU, making it a lot less likely that one of those workers would be executing.  Add instrumenting code or use a concurrency analyzer to get better insight.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out what is causing the high CPU utilization on these threads that are in a wait state. I don't yet know why it is happening though. When our application was a .NET 3.5 application someone here found and utilized an available threading assembly that someone had back-ported or something from .NET 4.0/4.5 for use with 3.5. This apparently has a defect in the Parallel.ForEach call or something. When I invoke this call I end up with these threads sitting around waiting, after the loop, consuming CPU. We confirmed with Microsoft that those threads were actually just waiting. Now we are 4.0 and I have switched to the task library available with 4.0 and the problem has gone away. I'll try to debug into the library when I get a chance to see if I can provide a specific reason why this was occuring.