# explorer thread using unusual amount of processor power, detect root/source of "issue"?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, cpu-usage

I was profiling an application I am developing, and I saw unusual explorer.exe processor usage, almost 15%!

This is very high for explorer, I launched process explorer and then I saw this:

[image]

I click "kill" and explorer works fine..

this happens every time explorer restarts / startsup.. How can I detect which application or what is causing that thread to launch and how do I prevent it from launching? My explorer works fine without it.

I suspect this is a virus but none of my AV software detects it..

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235279/debugging-rtluserthreadstart-in-process-explorer

Comment: connect a debugger and look for the thread that is burning CPU.

Comment: use xperf to get the cause: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140264 If you're unsure, zip and upload the ETL file.

Comment: I'm analyzing that ETL file I got, if I won't be able to identify the issue I'll upload it.

Comment: hm that tutorial uses another version of the ETL viewer? I can't find all of the options, here is the ETL file: [click](http://meet-helmond.nl/latency.zip), the process is explorer.exe with thread id 2208 which is causing the huge CPU usage.

Comment: yes, I use the old xperfview.exe which is better compared to the new WPA.exe. Btw, please use @MagicAndre1981 so that I get notified that you replied to me. I'll analyze the file now and post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a 3rd party components which creates dynamically code (green) and this code creates snapshots of programs (red) with this function: [kernel32.dll!CreateToolhelp32Snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[image]

Use [AutoRuns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to disable all 3rd party tools until you find the code which causes your CPU usage.

Comment: hm, GetProcessInformation... virus? ; o I'll try it now, thanks!

Comment: worked, thankyou, don't know which one it was but disabled ALL 3rd party extensions as for now.